# In python and pandas: editor struggles with large list, what are alternatives?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a list of strings that I compare to a specific column in an Excel file.

```
my_list = ('he', 'she', 'it')
df = pd.read_csv('large_table.csv')
```

Now I compare the items from my list with the content of a specific column and extract all rows that match:

```
result = df.loc[df['Interesting_column'].isin(my_list)]
```

This works fine for 20 list items, but I have over 2000 and basically, my editor gets so slow, he literally dies.

What can I do apart from splitting the list? I don't want to build a Database. Could I not somehow compare two dfs instead of iterating over this large list?

Answer (score 0):

If you make your list a set, then python will only take O(1) time to check if an item is present on the set.
Just add:

```
my_list = ('he', 'she', 'it')
my_set = set(my_list)
```

Or define it as:

```
my_set = {'he', 'she', 'it'}
```

Now you can keep using, `result = df.loc[df['Intresting_column'].isin(my_list)]`, which I highly recommend since that is how pandas is intended.